# Broadcasted model inside UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a model `mdl` and I am broadcasting it using

`mdl = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(mdl).value`

I have a pyspark UDF which accesses the model

```
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def func(row):
    result = mdl.predict(row.features)
    # Rest of the code
```

If I use a UDF, do I still need to broadcast my model `mdl`? Or does the UDF handles it on its own?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to broadcast your model variable because [broadcast variables](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-broadcast-variables/) are read-only shared variables that are cached and available on all nodes in a cluster.

You'll save time and resources once you broadcast it when you compare it to passing it to every single UDF usage.